# How can I locate a html tag that don't have an ID or class in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I want to locate only 'grape', what should I do? I tried using **document.querySelector**, but it doesn't work. I don't know how to locate html tags that don't have an ID or class.

```
        <h2 class="fruits">
            <ul>
                <li>apple</li>
                <li>grape</li>
            </ul>
        </h2>
```

Comment: There surely have to be obvious solutions. Why doesn't the li have the class or id "grape"? Why aren't the fruits in a javascript array? If you can't do something, it's probably because the code structure is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[document.evaluate()](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) lets you use xpath. The xpath `//*[.='grape']` should find elements with the text 'grape'.

This syntax is a bit ugly.

```
document.evaluate('//*[.="grape"]', document).iterateNext()
```

returns the first node matching the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem :

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fruits ul li")[1].style.color = "#009999";
```

```html
<h2 class="fruits">
     <ul>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>grape</li>
     </ul>
</h2>
```